# Ionic 2 Installation Fails - ENOENT, EPERM in installation on windows 10

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2, npm-install

I'm getting the following error ENOENT, EPERM while installing ionic on Windows 10 following instructions in http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/installation/

**npm config**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm config list
; cli configs
user-agent = "npm/3.10.8 node/v6.9.1 win32 x64"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\developer\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\WINDOWS\system32
; HOME = C:\Users\developer
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

**Commands used**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> node -v
v6.9.1
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm -v
3.10.8
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

*install ionic per instructions*

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install -g ionic cordova


  +-- request@2.51.0
  | `-- bl@0.9.5
  |   `-- readable-stream@1.0.34
  |     `-- inherits@2.0.3
  `-- unzip@0.1.9
    +-- fstream@0.1.31
    | +-- graceful-fs@3.0.11
    | | `-- natives@1.1.0
    | +-- inherits@2.0.3
    | `-- rimraf@2.5.4
    |   `-- glob@7.1.1
    |     +-- inflight@1.0.6
    |     +-- once@1.4.0
    |     `-- path-is-absolute@1.0.1
    +-- readable-stream@1.0.34
    | `-- inherits@2.0.3
    `-- setimmediate@1.0.5

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\developer\\AppData
\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic" "cord
ova"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-
2a0e0d71
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\developer\AppD
ata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-2a0e0d71' -> 'C:\Users\developer\AppD
ata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\developer\AppD
ata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-2a0e0d71' -> 'C:\Users\developer\AppD
ata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

What is the right way to go about this ?

similar issue on Ubuntu 12.04 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40340871/3206440)

**update**:- I tried running this as Admin, however the end result is the same with slightly different error messages.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install -g ionic cordova

    |       `-- strip-json-comments@1.0.4
    +-- repeating@1.1.3
    | `-- is-finite@1.0.2
    |   `-- number-is-nan@1.0.1
    +-- semver-diff@2.1.0
    `-- string-length@1.0.1

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\.cordova-lib.DELETE\node_modules\cordova-js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\.cordova-lib.DELETE\node_modules\cordova-js' -> 'C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js'
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:64:7
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:52:35
npm ERR!     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:52:11
npm ERR!     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR!     at asyncMap (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:51:8)
npm ERR!     at moveModules (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:61:5)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:56:70
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:48:26
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\.cordova-lib.DELETE\node_modules\cordova-js' -> 'C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\.cordova-lib.DELETE\node_modules\cordova-js' -> 'C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js'
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:64:7
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:52:35
npm ERR!     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:52:11
npm ERR!     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR!     at asyncMap (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:51:8)
npm ERR!     at moveModules (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:61:5)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:56:70
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mkdirp\index.js:48:26
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\.cordova-lib.DELETE\node_modules\cordova-js' -> 'C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js'
npm ERR!     at Error (native) parent: 'ionic-app-lib' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: already tried `rename 'C:\Users\developer\AppD
ata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-2a0e0d71' -> 'C:\Users\developer\AppD
ata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'` ?

Comment: @Ivaro18 - I do not see that source folder in C:\Users\developer\AppD ata\Roaming\npm\node_modules\

Comment: then install cordova, `npm install -g cordova`

Comment: why the down vote ?

Comment: @Ivaro18 - what is the reason for suggesting this ? based on Ionic documentation the command is `npm install -g ionic cordova` which should install both ionic and cordova- what makes you to suggest to install `cordova` ?

Comment: since npm is telling you you're missing `node_modules/cordova`

Comment: And I'm providing it as a suggestion indeed, not an answer since I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

Looking through different suggestions in other SO posts and resources.

Common suggestions

1. Delete `C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\npm` folder and create the npm manually and run as `Administrator`
2. Install npm again via `npm install -g npm`and run as `Administrator`
3. Create a different folder for npm

What really worked is #3 - i.e. to change the npm folder from the default npm installer choice to something other directory created by user.

**Steps**

1. Check current npm path

   `C:\>npm config get prefix`

   `C:\Users\developer\AppData\Roaming\npm`
   `C:\>`
2. Set npm and npm-cache folders to some user created directory

   `C:\>npm config set prefix C:\dev\npm_repo\npm --global`

   `C:\>npm config set cache C:\dev\npm_repo\npm-cache --global`
3. Run `npm install -g <some_module>` to test that the module gets installed in the dir `C:\dev\npm_repo\npm`
4. Run `npm install -g ionic cordova` from command prompt as `Administrator`
5. Add path `C:\dev\npm_repo\npm` to `PATH` environment variable

Note:-

In step 3, I ran `npm install -g jshint` as a normal user and `jshint` got installed fine. However, running `npm install -g ionic cordova` as a normal user still gave error as below. Hence in step 4 for ionic the installation was ran as `Administrator`

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path C:\dev\npm_repo\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\dev\npm_repo\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp' -> 'C:\dev\npm_repo\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\ionic-app-lib\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.node-gyp.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at moveAway (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:38:5)
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:27:7)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

The final result of running `npm install -g ionic cordova` as `Administrator`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g ionic cordova
C:\dev\npm_repo\npm\cordova -> C:\dev\npm_repo\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
C:\dev\npm_repo\npm\ionic -> C:\dev\npm_repo\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
C:\dev\npm_repo\npm
+-- cordova@6.4.0
| +-- cordova-lib@6.4.0
| +-- insight@0.8.3
| +-- nopt@3.0.1
| `-- update-notifier@0.5.0
`-- ionic@2.1.4
  +-- @ionic/app-generators@0.0.3
  +-- cli-table@0.3.1
  +-- expand-tilde@1.2.0
  +-- gulp@3.8.8
  +-- gulp-util@3.0.7
  | `-- dateformat@1.0.12
  |   `-- meow@3.7.0
  |     +-- normalize-package-data@2.3.5
  |     `-- read-pkg-up@1.0.1
  |       `-- read-pkg@1.1.0
  +-- inquirer@0.11.2
  +-- ionic-app-lib@2.1.2
  | +-- cordova-lib@6.1.0
  | | +-- cordova-common@1.1.1
  | | | `-- osenv@0.1.3
  | | |   +-- os-homedir@1.0.1

## snipped ##

    +-- match-stream@0.0.2
    | `-- buffers@0.1.1
    +-- pullstream@0.4.1
    | +-- over@0.0.5
    | `-- slice-stream@1.0.0
    +-- readable-stream@1.0.34
    | +-- core-util-is@1.0.2
    | +-- inherits@2.0.3
    | +-- isarray@0.0.1
    | `-- string_decoder@0.10.31
    `-- setimmediate@1.0.5


C:\WINDOWS\system32>

C:\Windows\System32>ionic -v
2.1.4


C:\Windows\System32>cordova -v
6.4.0

C:\Windows\System32>
```