# "npm ERR!" When running React application or finds npm version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

Whenever I try to find my Npm version, it shows me a list of errors which starts with "npm ERR!", and then shows me the npm version. Secondly whenever I run my React Application in VS Code, it shows me the same errors "npm ERR!" and then run the application.

[image]

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, please post the actual error that is being returned by the console. Also, within your error file, it is referencing an error log. if you can post the code from there, that would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js/Windows error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\RT\AppData\Roaming\npm'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm)

Comment: @logos_164. Following are the errors

C:\Users\Saim>npm --version
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn D:\Nodejs\node.exe
npm ERR! path D:\Nodejs\node.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent spawn D:\Nodejs\node.exe ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! Callback called more than once.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Saim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-17T04_46_11_791Z-debug.log
6.11.3

Comment: @sidhantmanchanda that solution didn't worked for me