# npx create-react-app doesn't seem to work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I am trying to create a React app boiler plate by running the following command

`npx create-react-app my-app`

I get the following errors

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\dejean\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\dejean\AppData\Roaming\npm'   
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dejean\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-27T18_53_22_682Z-debug-0.log
```

I use node 18.16.1 and npm 9.5.1

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm

Answer (score 17):

Run
`npm install -g npm`
to upgrade Node Package Manager

Comment: Even though I had a fresh install of node.js, and `npm --version` returned successfully, this solution fixed the issue for me.

Comment: After running `npm install -g npm` the error went away and it started asking for the package installation that i was orignally installing.

Answer (score 4):

Just create the folder **npm** in the directory C:\Users\dejean\AppData\Roaming.

I hope this helped you !

Answer (score 0):

Might be case with many, so I created a directory let's call it `demo1` and `cd demo1` but then deleted the directory using UI so when I tried run `npm -v` or `npm i -g npm` was throwing the same error.

So make sure you cd into a valid directory when performing it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called npm in the path "C:\Users\dejean\AppData\Roaming" and install the node js in this npm folder.

Answer (score -5):

The error you're encountering seems to be related to npm not being able to find a specific file or directory. It appears that the command you ran is trying to access the directory "C:\Users\dejean\AppData\Roaming\npm", but it is unable to locate it.

Here are a few steps you can try to resolve this issue:

Make sure you have Node.js and npm installed on your system. You can verify this by running the following commands in your command prompt or terminal:

```
node -v
npm -v
```

If Node.js and npm are installed, try updating npm to the latest version by running the following command:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

If the issue persists, it's possible that there may be a problem with your npm configuration or installation. You can try resetting the npm configuration by running the following command:

```
npm config set prefix ""
```

After resetting the npm configuration, try running the create-react-app command again:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Please do not post AI-generated output here: it is forbidden on Stack Overflow. You'd better delete this before you get yourself into trouble: we take plagiarism seriously here.