Error in installing react js through npx create-react-app xyz
When I fire the above command in the terminal it shows error like
npm Err! code-ENOENT
npm Err! syscall lstat
npm Err! path
While in  my instructor laptops properly works in this command. I am attaching the terminal image snapshot for reference:enter image description here
I tried the other ways like online editors and searching on yt.

Please check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76567872/npx-create-react-app-doesnt-seem-to-work

Run npm install -g npm and then run npx create-react-app my-app again

I have found out the solution. To solve the issue,you have the following ways:
1.)- just create a folder (named npm) in the AppData folder(sometimes hidden) in the users folder of the main drive.
2.) Use npm install -g npm and then run npx create-app my-app.
