# NPX Stopped Working immediately - errno -4058

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

Today I ran an `npx` command and it doesn't work. None of the `npx` commands work. I even uninstalled and reinstalled Node.js

Here are the [complete logs](https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/3ede21f34074487eb9cf73dcd60fd699)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So I just read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25095327/11727541) that creating a folder with the name `npm` solved the issue and the same for me. So simply create a folder named `npm` at the path. In my case, a new folder at `C:\Users\maxpr\AppData\Roaming` solved the issue for me