# I tried to download Node.js again, but it still won't solve the problem, and I tried to create Next app, and I had the same problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPsOM.png)

I tried to download Node.js again, but it still won't solve the problem, and I tried to create Next app, and I had the same problem help me to solve my problem please .
I tried to download Node.js again, but it still won't solve the problem, and I tried to create Next app, and I had the same problem help me to solve my problem please.
I tried to download Node.js again, but it still won't solve the problem, and I tried to create Next app, and I had the same problem help me to solve my problem please.
I tried to download Node.js again, but it still won't solve the problem, and I tried to create Next app, and I had the same problem help me to solve my problem please.

Comment: Did you try to download Node.js again?

Comment: can you show us your ```package.json``` ?

Comment: Please paste the effort as text

Comment: PS D:\React> npx -v
9.6.7
PS D:\React> npx create-react-app
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ebraheem ali mahrous\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\ebraheem ali mahrous\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ebraheem ali mahrous\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-17T08_20_19_861Z-debug-0.log
PS D:\React>

Comment: yes, i tried to download nodejs again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js/Windows error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\RT\AppData\Roaming\npm'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm)