# How to install react in the terminal when the VS code editor is taking a path that dosen't exist

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

[VS Code editor taking the path that dosen't exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbvXh.png)

tried to install react using npx command on the terminal.
i tried all the things they said would work in youtube and it didnt work.
how should i change the path and the quick way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

Make sure NPM is properly installed on your computer.

First, try running `npm install npm -g`.

If this doesn't work, try creating the `npm` folder in the directory. i.e.
navigate to `C:\Users\prana\AppData\Roaming\`, right-click and select new "New Folder" and name it `npm`.

Here is a similar question posted:
[Node.js/Windows error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\RT\AppData\Roaming\npm'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm)