# tried running npx create-react-app my-app in cmd after installing node but got bunch of errors

Tags: node.js, create-react-app

so I wanted to start create-react-app for a react project, I had earlier installed nodejs. In cmd, I entered the command  `npx create-react-app my-app`. And I got the following error;

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

I'm not really sure of what to do. I've done a look up on the error though I didn't come across anything exactly like this. But I read up alot of ways related errors could be diagnose.

I thought to try npx create-react-app@latest my-app instead, but this didn't work either.
So, I attempted to clean the cache, but got a warning from node;

```
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues
npm ERR!   by treating integrity mismatches as cache misses.  As a result,
npm ERR!   data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid.  If you
npm ERR!   want to make sure everything is consistent, use `npm cache verify`
npm ERR!   instead.  Deleting the cache can only make npm go slower, and is
npm ERR!   not likely to correct any problems you may be encountering!
npm ERR!
npm ERR!   On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer,
npm ERR!   or race conditions that depend on the timing of writing to an empty
npm ERR!   cache, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a
npm ERR!   temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!   If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command
npm ERR!   with --force.

NB: my node version is v18.18.0
and npm version is 9.8.1
```

Thanks for the anticipated inputs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js/Windows error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\RT\AppData\Roaming\npm'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm)