# unable to create a react app with npx since I am getting an error

Tags: reactjs, node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFpoI.png)when I try to enter the npx create-react-app this error appears

I do have node v18.18.0 however when I try the comand it is not working, I tried to see what can be the error however nothing it is coming up clearly I have create a new file that is empty.

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm

Answer (score 0):

Just create the missing directory (npm). Manually create the npm directory as follows.

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm
```