# How to install react for the very first time on windows

Tags: reactjs, node.js

When installing the react app for the very first time it is giving this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ansar\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\ansar\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ansar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-08T21_24_35_673Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried googling it, reinstalled node js

Comment: Have you installed Node.js correctly? What do you see if you run "node -v" and "npm -v" in your terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js/Windows error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\RT\AppData\Roaming\npm'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm)

Comment: Context, please. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.