# Can't install react app using npx create-react-app my-app

Tags: javascript, npm, npx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjv0m.jpg)
Unable to create the react app using npx create-react-app my-app...
I am getting the errors as mentioned in the image.

Tried using npm init but didn't work for me.
Added node.js and vs code to path.

Comment: https://dev.to/ag2byte/create-react-app-is-officially-dead-h7o

Comment: I think the problem is related to the npm installation itself. Please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25093276/node-js-windows-error-enoent-stat-c-users-rt-appdata-roaming-npm

Answer (score 0):

The `npx` project is now old-school.
The new approach is using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project) from their website you have a comprehensive guide that should do the work to get you started.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).