# Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider “MSDASQL” for linked server

Tags: sql-server, node.js, linked-server

[I am familiar with this post on the matter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362108/cannot-initialize-the-data-source-object-of-ole-db-provider-msdasql-for-linked)

I have the same situation as described in this post, however the accepted answer is not solving my problem.

#### SPECIFICS

From my Microsoft SQL Server 2012 console, logged in as Administrator (with domain credentials), I can successfully run this command:

```
select * from openquery(MyLinkedServer, 'select * from my_linked_server_table')
```

I can run it wrapped in a stored procedure as well.

```
exec runMyLinkedServerCommand 1234
```

I have Node.js running as my web server, and connect up with [TDS drivers](https://npmjs.org/package/tedious). I pass a SQL Server account as the credentials to Node.js, not a Windows account.

I try to run the stored procedure through Node.js using an XHR request from my browser, and I get the above mentioned error:

```
Cannot initialize the data source object 
of OLE DB provider “MSDASQL” for linked server ("myLinkedServer")
```

The [above mentioned main post on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362108/cannot-initialize-the-data-source-object-of-ole-db-provider-msdasql-for-linked) states to enable access to the Temp Directory on the windows account running SQL Server. I did this, but this doesn't change anything. I don't know if running Node.js has any bearing in any of this, or what else to try.

I have successfully run the query from SQL Server Management Studio under the same SQL credentials that my Node.js TDS module is using.

I am at a loss at what else to try.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to SQL Server database from Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309540/connect-to-sql-server-database-from-node-js)

Comment: @PaulSweatte, that's the first thing I said in my post above. Lol

Comment: 10309540 != 1362108. 10309540 does not mention the word `temp`.