# SQL Server connection to node js

Tags: sql-server, node.js, database, sql-server-2005

I am trying to establish a connection between nodejs project and server running Microsoft SQL Server 2005. I am using a node module `mssql`, but I get these errors when I am attempting to create a connection:

> { [ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 123.123.12.1:1433 in 15000ms]
>   name: 'ConnectionError',
>   message: 'Failed to connect to 123.123.12.1:1433 in 15000ms',
>   code: 'ETIMEOUT' }

My connection being made by

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var dbConfig = {
    server:'123.123.12.1',
    database:'testingDB',
    user:'userName',
    password:'pass',
    port:1433
};

function getEmp() {
    var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
    var req = new sql.Request(conn);

    conn.connect(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
    else {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
}

getEmp();
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I am using a cloud 9 IDE if that helps.

Comment: actually, there is a great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31989348/5277639

Answer (score 14):

Put your `var req = new sql.Request(conn)` inside connect.

```
// config for your database
var config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'mypassword',
    server: 'localhost', 
    database: 'SchoolDB' 
};

// connect to your database
sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query('select * from Student', function (err, recordset) {

        if (err) console.log(err)

        // send records as a response
        res.send(recordset);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

It work for me. First install mssql by npm (**npm install --save mssql**)

```
var sql = require('mssql');
```

**for local sql server**

```
var sqlConfig = {
  user: 'sa',
  password: 'admin',
  server: 'CBMOBILESHAMIM\\SQLEXPRESS',  
  database: 'databaseName'
};
```

**for azure server**

```
var sqlConfig = {
  user: 'adminLogin',
  password: 'admin',
  server: 'severname.database.windows.net',    // don't add tcp & port number
  database: 'databaseName',
  options: {
    encrypt: true
  }
};
```

**Now connect to server**

```
(async function () {
  try {
    console.log("sql connecting......")
    let pool = await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
    let result = await pool.request()
      .query('select * from Subject')  // subject is my database table name

    console.log(result )

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})()
```

for more details check [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)

Comment: Very thorough answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var webconfig = {

user: 'login',

password: 'sa@123',

server: 'localhost', 

database: 'TestDB',



options: {

    encrypt: false // Use this if you're on Windows Azure 

}

  }




 var express = require('express');

 var sql = require('mssql');

 var http = require('http');


var connection = new sql.Connection(webconfig, function(err) {
var request = new sql.Request(connection); 
request.query('select * from Users', function(err, recordset) {
   if(err)      // ... error checks 
        console.log('Database connection error');

console.dir("User Data: "+recordset);
});
 });

 var app = express();

 var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
```

or visit here : https://nodejsbeginersprograms.blogspot.in/2017/02/nodejs-basic-tutorial-with-mssql.html