# Sequelize : Cannot connect to SQL Server - incorrect port is being passed

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server instance but the wrong port is being defined when I attempt to connect.

> Unable to connect to the database: { SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
>   at Handshake._callback (C:\test\ExpressGeneric\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:80:20)
>   at Handshake.Sequence.end (C:\test\ExpressGeneric\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
>   at Protocol.handleNetworkError (C:\test\ExpressGeneric\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:363:14)
>   at Connection._handleNetworkError (C:\test\ExpressGeneric\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:428:18)
>           at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>           at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>           at emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8)
>           at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
>         name: 'SequelizeConnectionRefusedError',
>         message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306',

I have no idea why this is happening.

Here are my configuration settings. I only changed the pass and db for this post, I am using the correct credentials when connecting.

```
config.sql = {
    host: 'sql2012dev',
    database: 'db',
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'pass'
}
```

And here is my connection.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.sql.database, config.sql.user, config.sql.password, {
  host: config.sql.host,
  dialect: 'mssql',
  port: '1433',
  driver: 'tedious',
  dialectOptions:{
   instanceName: MSSQLSERVER 
  },
  define: {
    timestamps: false
  },
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },
})
```

I'm able to connect to it remotely just fine using the management studio. Named Pipes and SQL Browser is enabled.

I also had to run npm mysql just to get the app to start.

Here are my dependencies just in case

```
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "2.1.5",
    "body-parser": "1.17.1",
    "client-sessions": "0.7.0",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "debug": "2.6.2",
    "ejs": "2.5.6",
    "express": "4.15.2",
    "helmet": "3.5.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "morgan": "1.8.1",
    "mssql": "^4.0.4",
    "nsp": "2.6.3",
    "sendgrid": "4.8.0",
    "sequelize": "^3.14.1",
    "tedious": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have not specified the port number in your configuration. Specify the port in your configuration as specified in [NodeJsConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309540/connect-to-sql-server-database-from-node-js#31989348)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the deal was but I am able to connect now. I am wondering if the positioning of the variables was a problem.

```html
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(db,userName,password,{
    dialect: 'mssql',
    host: hostName,
    port: 1433,
    logging: false,
    dialectOptions: {
      requestTimeout: 30000,
      encrypt: true
    }
  })
```

Comment: In the first example you were using port as a string '1433', instead of 1433 as number

Answer (score 3):

Have you changed the default port of mysql. If not then use default port in your configuration.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.sql.database, config.sql.user, config.sql.password, {
  host: config.sql.host,
  dialect: 'mssql',
  port: '3306', //-------------> change port here
  driver: 'tedious',
  dialectOptions:{
   instanceName: MSSQLSERVER 
  },
  define: {
    timestamps: false
  },
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },
})
```

Also make sure your server is started and accessible from the machine where you are running your application.

Comment: I'm not using MySQL. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. I have not changed the port and yes, it is on and I am able to connect to it remotely, just as I stated in my post. The problem is that port 3306 is being defined somewhere else and I have no idea why. I do not want to use port 3306 because that is not the port that is being used by the database server. The port that is being used is 1433.