# Simplest way to use ODBC with SQL Server and Node.js on Windows

Tags: sql-server, node.js, odbc

From @Chris answer [Node.js and Microsoft SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156806/node-js-and-microsoft-sql-server/22658512#22658512)

> Using node-mssql that wraps Tedious is the best way to go. Especially
>   if you have node running on Windows, because both modules are written
>   in pure javascript.

I'd gladly go along with that but what if I want to use ODBC?

I found https://www.npmjs.org/package/eos that but I'm skeptical as it's rather low in popularity.

I have done a lot of research but I think I'm not looking at the right place. Note it's the first time I have to use both SQL Server and ODBC.

Thank you for helping me shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

In production I am using a combination of `node-odbc` (for most requests) and `eos` (for streaming media, since it supports sending/receiving parameter values in chunks, as well as receiving column values in chunks). It works pretty well.

Disclaimer: I wrote `eos`.