# Access to SQLServer with Node.js on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, node.js, express, connector

I'm trying to write a REST service with Node.js and Express and I need to connect to a SLQServer 2000 database. I've tried the Microsoft connector but it's not working on linux, according to them:

> The Microsoft Driver for Node.JS for SQL Server is currently available
>   as a preview release, and relies on run-time components that are only
>   available on the Microsoft Windows and Windows Azure operating
>   systems.

I've also tried node.js's modules tdm and tedious with no success... Any idea?

Comment: what about mono ? I mean - try getting node work on mono, for example. cause afaik - mono can talk to MS SQL

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to a remote Microsoft SQL server from Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728385/connecting-to-a-remote-microsoft-sql-server-from-node-js)

Comment: question you're quoting presents solutions that didn't work for me, as explained in the question

Comment: Can you provide more detail on why, for instance, you could not use tedious?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [tedious](https://www.npmjs.org/package/tedious) again. Version 0.2 fixed compatibility with TDS 7.1  (SQL Server 2000).

Comment: I use tedious on Ubuntu to connect SQL-SERVER on other server, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge)?

[Leverage SQL Server with node.js.](http://blog.codeship.io/2014/04/22/leverage-sql-server-with-node-js-using-edge-js.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install mssql
```

I believe that to be the generally accepted best solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Espresso Logic](http://www.espressologic.com)to create a REST API and then call that from .NodeJS

Answer (score -1):

Even if its a year old question, thought of answering it as it is the first thing that shows up in google for the question.

There is [node-sqlserver](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver/) maintained by Microsoft. The last commit was made 5 months ago though.

Install with `$ npm install msnodesql` .

Comment: Ubuntu is not supported. It's just for windows.

Comment: The question explicitly asks about linux support and your answer is a Windows only solution