# Is there any possible way to run select sql query by jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server

Is there any possible way to excute the select sql query using javascript or jquery.

for ex : i want to run the query like

```
select * from abc
```

So, can I excute this query using javascript or jquery.

If yes then please guide me.
If no then please give me the reason.

ThankYou

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7373216/492258)

Comment: Simple answer, nope

Answer (score 1):

From browser-side JavaScript, no, not really.

You can use server-side Node.js JavaScript, but you'll want to do the query directly from the server with some language (literally any server-side language).

Running queries from the client is not only technically difficult, but it's also a huge security risk as your users could run any query.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn´t use client javascript to access databases, mostly because security.

but a example:
( from [How to connect to SQL Server database from JavaScript in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser))

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;

var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
   document.write(rs.fields(1));
   rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;
```

Better way is call ajax function to a code behind method and query from there.

Comment: Note that `ActiveXObject` is IE only. Even IE's successor, Edge, doesn't support it any more.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use AJAX. To perform any action.