# JavaScript Chart Controls in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, database

Need Your Help. How to pass values in javascript from sql in asp.net.

like I developed few bar graphs with java scripts. but the values of X and Y axis is programetically written but I want the values from database(SQL).

how can I do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript    you can use this link for your problem

Comment: Thanks  Ankur Singh can we imports the values from excel sheet  like can we import the values of x and y axis of the bar graph with javascript

Comment: ya sure.in that case first you have to import to the sql server.

Comment: please thumbs up if you feel helpful from given link :)

Comment: Can you explain me with an example. is that you mean to say that I should import the excel sheet to SQL 2008. and use it.