# Is a database the only backend we need?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backend, frontend

I'm a frontend developer with very low knowledge of backend.
I was wondering with todays javascript libraries such as backbone.js and cloud serviced databases like stackmob, mongolab etc.

Could we build everything "frontend" now and just fetch the data from one of these databases?

Comment: This has been asked sooo many times. Have a look at this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript

Comment: Also sorry, but StackOverflow isn't the right place for debate-style questions.

Comment: Have you looked at CouchDB-related stuff?  Might be what you're after. http://couchapp.org/page/index

Comment: I'm sorry. I might not be the search guru I thought I was. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is something that is becoming increasingly viable, although there are still challenges that need to be overcome - authentication is a big one (you can't simply store your data store credentials clientside like you might do serverside as anybody could find them and abuse them), although efforts are being made to address this.

Take a look at [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) as an example of exactly this kind of thing. Their [examples page](https://www.firebase.com/examples.html) shows examples of applications built without your own backend being required. They just announced their [security API](http://blog.firebase.com/post/38234264120/the-new-firebase-security-api) this week as a means of addressing the authentication side of things.

Comment: Thanks, that'll hopefully bring me up to speed.

Answer (score 0):

You must have proxy on your client side to send data to some cloud serviced and allowing cross-domain but you must have origin domain set on cloud serviced to you domain (which can be a problem).

For proxy you can use Java applet, flash object, html5 socket or XMLHttpRequests.

This is not easy and some of this don't working on all modern browsers.