# How can I connect form to a ADO database with HTML or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, database, vb6

This week I started working with HTML and databases. I'm not sure this is the best way to do it, but at the moment it seemed like the best option considering my knowledge.

I have a form with one `textarea` and one `textfield` used for the date (with format `dd-mm-yyyy`) and I have two buttons to update a query in the database. One button makes the number in the `textarea` valid at the give date, and the other just makes it invalid at the date.

I know the database is based on ADODB, so my question is, do I have to open a connection to get the querys just like in VB6? or it's different in HTML/Javascript? How do I do to update the querys from the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what's listed here: [How to connect to SQL Server database from JavaScript in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript) .  However, your database connection info will be visible on the client's machine, meaning anyone can connect to your database using that connection string.  You've been warned.

Comment: It's ok, this will be used for internally only. Thanks