# Easiest, Most Efficient way of associating data from different tables Without Associations

Tags: javascript, sql, associations, relational-database, facebook-fql

This is something that has intrigued me a lot recently. It's a general SQL/Relational Database problem coming from a guy who prefers Mongo.

What I want is, to, as such, associate data from different tables in the most efficient, easiest way, **without using associations and assuming I can't restructure or re-model the db.**

So, for example, with FQL (which doesn't have associations), if I asked for the `name` and `eid` of all the events my current user has been invited to, I'd also like to know whether my current user is going, but that info is in the 'event_member' table.

In this instance I've an interest in another column (`rsvp_status`) in `event_member`, one that I'd like to be associated with the columns from `event`, i.e `eid` and `name`.

In this case the instinct may be to say that since every event has a `name`, an `eid` and a `rsvp_status` then we could say sort by `eid` and then match each nth item (for n=1 to whatever), because there's guaranteed to be the same number, but there are many cases when we can't do that.

And I know I could do separate queries and then iterate through and match them by `eid`, but basically **I'm looking for a generic, simple,efficient solution for the associations idea if one exists.** Preferably in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for here is a simple JOIN of two or more tables. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
You do not have to have any relations between tables in order to perform JOINS. The relations are just a constraint to ensure that bad/invalid data can't propagete to the tables. For example an event_member with eid of unexisting user. Anyway you are free to JOIN tables as you like :)

Here is a way to connect to Sql Server using javascript [How to connect to SQL Server database from JavaScript in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript)

Comment: Knew it had to be something to do with them, I knew literally adding two sql queries together would work nicely, thanks :)

Comment: I recommend Joe Celko's "SQL for Smarties" book for some advanced tricks and topics.