# Query sql server using extjs

Tags: sql-server, http, extjs

I want to query **SQL server via HTTP or some other way** but should be from web browser using **ExtJS**. How can i do this? An example working code could help me more.

**NOTE: The SQL server has authentication to be done before querying it**

Comment: Before asking you should search at least SO and any other search engine of your choice like google. Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript

Comment: The sql server autheintication can be done in your code java, because when you connecto to the database you must put the password and user of the database. It is a little difficult to explain how to do all the project, but the first at all is decided if you want ot use servlet or trying spring, hibernate, etc.. in this case with servlet is "easy to do". You need for example the following class (one for each dao for each one form, one for your database consults, one for the set and get of each element in each database (beans), and one for each servlet), then you need the web content...

Comment: where you have each one form (jsp calling js).There are a lot of post in this forum about EXtjs, servlets, sql, etc.... if you need better help, do more specifically consults).