# How do I store the data returned by Google Places API to my database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-maps, google-places-api

How do I store the data returned by Google Places API to my database?

This is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Creating a Custom jQuery Plugin</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.accordion.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.accordion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('dl#my-accordion').accordion({open:true});
    });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="gmap_canvas"></div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="button">
            <label for="gmap_where">Where:</label>
            <input id="gmap_where" type="text" name="gmap_where" /></div>
        <div id="button2" class="button" onclick="findAddress(); return false;">Search for address</div>
        <form action="save.php" method="post">
            <div class="button">
                <label for="gmap_keyword">Keyword (optional):</label>
                <input id="gmap_keyword" type="text" name="gmap_keyword" /></div>
            <div class="button">
                <label for="gmap_type">Type:</label>
                <select id="gmap_type">
                    <option value="art_gallery">art_gallery</option>
                    <option value="atm">atm</option>
                    <option value="bank">bank</option>
                    <option value="bar">bar</option>
                    <option value="cafe">cafe</option>
                    <option value="food">food</option>
                    <option value="hospital">hospital</option>
                    <option value="police">police</option>
                    <option value="store">store</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="button">
                <label for="gmap_radius">Radius:</label>
                <select id="gmap_radius">
                    <option value="500">500</option>
                    <option value="1000">1000</option>
                    <option value="1500">1500</option>
                    <option value="5000">5000</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" value="40.7143528" />
            <input type="hidden" id="lng" name="lng" value="-74.0059731" />
            <div onclick="findplaces(); return false;"><input type="submit" value="Search for objects"class="button" id="button1" /></div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the script

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var markers = Array();
var infos = Array();

function initialize() {
    // prepare Geocoder
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    // set initial position (New York)
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7143528,-74.0059731);

    var myOptions = { // default map options
        zoom: 14,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
}

// clear overlays function
function clearOverlays() {
    if (markers) {
        for (i in markers) {
            markers[i].setMap(null);
        }
        markers = [];
        infos = [];
    }
}

// clear infos function
function clearInfos() {
    if (infos) {
        for (i in infos) {
            if (infos[i].getMap()) {
                infos[i].close();
            }
        }
    }
}

// find address function
function findAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("gmap_where").value;

    // script uses our 'geocoder' in order to find location by address name
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { // and, if everything is ok

            // we will center map
            var addrLocation = results[0].geometry.location;
            map.setCenter(addrLocation);

            // store current coordinates into hidden variables
            document.getElementById('lat').value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById('lng').value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            // and then - add new custom marker
            var addrMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: addrLocation,
                map: map,
                title: results[0].formatted_address,
                icon: 'marker.png'
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}

// find custom places function
function findPlaces() {

    // prepare variables (filter)
    var type = document.getElementById('gmap_type').value;
    var radius = document.getElementById('gmap_radius').value;
    var keyword = document.getElementById('gmap_keyword').value;

    var lat = document.getElementById('lat').value;
    var lng = document.getElementById('lng').value;
    var cur_location = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    // prepare request to Places
    var request = {
        location: cur_location,
        radius: radius,
        types: [type]
    };
    if (keyword) {
        request.keyword = [keyword];
    }

    // send request
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, createMarkers);
}

// create markers (from 'findPlaces' function)
function createMarkers(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

        // if we have found something - clear map (overlays)
        clearOverlays();

        // and create new markers by search result
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    } else if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
        alert('Sorry, nothing is found');
    }
}

// creare single marker function
function createMarker(obj) {

    // prepare new Marker object
    var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: obj.geometry.location,
        map: map,
        title: obj.name
    });
    markers.push(mark);

    // prepare info window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<img src="' + obj.icon + '" /><font style="color:#000;">' + obj.name +
        '<br />Rating: ' + obj.rating + '<br />Vicinity: ' + obj.vicinity + '</font>'
    });

    // add event handler to current marker
    google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function() {
        clearInfos();
        infowindow.open(map,mark);
    });
    infos.push(infowindow);
}

// initialization
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I just need an idea on how to dump the data returned by Google Places API in a database. Thanks!

Comment: Please read the [Terms of Use](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3) (b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content. You must not pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i) limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily (and in no event for more than 30 calendar days), securely, and in a manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service; and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs Documentation specifically permits you to store.

Answer (score 0):

You should post the result you got from google map API to your own server, maybe using your own API, and store it on your server.

Comment: Sorry. I'm fairly new to Google APIs and don't quite grasp how to manage data. Google returns results as JSON object? If so, how do I get those and store them in my database?

Answer (score 0):

[Interacting with database via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/857688/1671639) is although possible, it is not recommended.

As  Quentin commented "**low security environment is not web programming**"

So the best approach is using [**Web Services**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) (via API)

- It seems you need to store lat/lon to your database(if needed parse
  the lat/lon returned by Google API).
- Then create JSON objects out of it.
- Next learn about [**Ajax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX),
  which is going to send data to, and retrieve data from, a server
  asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the
  display and behavior of the existing page.

Hope you understand.