# Persist data on server with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, database, web-applications, persistence

I'd like to create a small JS, HTML & CSS-only web application for my personal use with some kind of MVC-framework (like ember.js). My big requirement is that I want to persist the data **permanently** on the server where I run the web-application.

Is that achievable and what are good frameworks for it? 
If something needs to run on the server I want it to be lightweight and easy to setup.

I need to be able to query the data. After a while there will be a few thousand rows in the database. Joins etc. won't be required.

Comment: This question is far too broad. It could be highly focused (e.g. with various limitations such as I-don't-have-my-own-server-or-want-to-administer-anything), but then would still likely be a "recommendation".

Comment: It's hard to come up with exact requirements. I guess there are a ton of options. What I am looking are for are in fact just some recommendations.

Comment: @Hedge Which is an off-topic question, unfortunately :| I can give you lots of what *I* like but (even if you were into my same language/OS ecosystem) it would only be a recommendation.

Comment: Hit me up if you can and I'll delete the question.

Comment: google storage or amazon s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly possible, but you'll need somethign running on the server to swallow the data.

Typically you have serverside code which interacts with your data store to prevent users from manipulating your databases.

Comment: ok, can you name some lightweight and easy to setup options?

Comment: Well, if you want to get into trouble here's the Client-side option
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript

Server Side JS frameworks do exist, like Node JS.  Are you administering the server or are you running on someone else's stack?

Comment: It's a vServer some web hosting company runs for me.

Comment: No, I can install whatever I want on it. I already built the app in PHP but want to reinvent it with something I didn't use yet. I just wanted something more lightweight than rails.

Comment: More information than you could want http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40772/discussion-between-infernalrapture-and-hedge)

Answer (score 0):

You can stick with JSON/Javascript and use CouchDB: http://couchdb.apache.org/.

It allows you to read/write data directly from Javascript, so you don't have to write server side code.

Other ideas to stay in the JSON/Javascript world - you can write from client side to a Node.js machine that writes to Mongo. Pure JSON/Javascript all the way down.