# Create, read, update, delete, search - dataTable

Tags: javascript, mysql, datatable

Here I have an dataTable: http://jsbin.com/aMAQUWe/1/edit with code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
        data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Parcele ha');

        data.addRows([
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true, 1200],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false, 344],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true, 888],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true,999]
        ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style='background:#fff'; id='table_div'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

On server side I have a mysql table: `Employee` and column: `name, salary, time, parcele`

How I can connect my DataTable with my mysql dataBase and to make it workable for CRUD functions (create,read,update,delete,search) ?

Is there any plugin or example, tutorial how I can make it?

*sorry for my english, its bad, but I;m learning hard*

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to connect to you DB directly from client? if so Read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript) first.
As mentioned at the link its a bad practice.
The right way to do so is to connect to your DB from the server side (using: `PHP` ,`Node.js`, etc) and dynamically create the page with the data table you want.