# Upload PHP with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I need to put a javascript variable in js file to php variable in php file to do action in sql db later.
I use local server Apache to do this. My javascript variable is "uid"

In my js file I've insert this :

```
function post()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "proc.php",
    data: uid, 

  });   
}
```

In my php file named "proc.php" the code is :

```
<?php

$myvar = $_POST['uid'];
echo 'myvar';

?>
```

Is it possible to display by echo "myvar" in alert box to know if my code works ?

Comment: you will need php or node.js for this, you can't update your db with client side javascript

Comment: Read this maybe help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript

Comment: @baao yes you can although its not recommended since it exposes your connection string to the public

Comment: @meda I have to admit I never thought about the possibility because of security concerns. But it seems that you are right.

Comment: I've try to send it with Ajax $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "proc.php",
   data: "duration",
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   }
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was data are'nt in Json format :

This code works fine :

In pour js file :

```
     var data = {
        fn: "filename", // json format
        test : "...",
        ....
                };

     $.post("proc.php", data);
```

And in your php file "proc.php", you can get the variable with :

```
$nom = $_POST['fn'];
$id = $_POST['test'];
$var = ...
```

After you can display data with an echo, and insert it in a div