# Insert a file into Database using pur Html and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, database, file-upload

I'm looking for the simplest way to **upload** a **file** and **insert** it into a table in a **database** using pur **HTML** and **JAVASCRIPT**.

There is no way to use **JAVASCRPIT framworks** or **HTML5** since I'm trying to add a **custom** **HTML** **part** into a complex application.

I've found many examples using **PHP**, **HTML5** and **JAVASCRIPT** but I'm really looking for pur simple **JAVASCIPT** and **HTML** script.

Ismail

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  You need to have *something* on the server that will handle your uploaded file.  JAVASCRIPT and HTML5 are about what happens in the browser, not what the server does. You could have a Node JS server that runs Javascript on the server (rather than PHP), but I don't think that's what you mean by "Pure JAVASCRIPT / HTML".

Comment: Javascript has always been able to talk to dbs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript  There are strong obvious reasons not to.  You can insert the file into the database as a blob and retrieve it, etc... so can anybody else who does a view source.  Your db would have to be publicly accessible, which is also a no no 99% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant upload a file to a server with a client side language. You need at least some server side activity to handle the incoming file