# Connecting to SQL from client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server

Is it possible to connect to a SQL database, `e.g. a SQL Server database`, from javascript (client-side). Preferably using an `ODBC` or `OLEDB` connection.

I know this normally isn't recommended, and you should always connect from the server-side, but I want people to connect to their own SQL databases on their own local machines.

I have found examples to do this using `ActiveX` objects, but this only works in Internet Explorer, and I don't want to be restricted by this.

Comment: If you want provide users a remote access to their databases - why not do that with a proper DB manager application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect to SQL Server database from JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript)

Comment: @Zerkms This is initially a project for myself. I wanted to see if I could replace the default SQL Management Studio client by one in a browser, so I don't need to install it all the time when i need it. Meanwhile learning a bit more about javascript.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any browser-side database drivers, but perhaps check out PostgREST:
https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest
It wraps PostgreSQL in a simple REST API, so you don't need any additional server software.

Comment: It's not exactly what I need. I'm really searching for a way to call a database from the client-side. But it seems that, except for ActiveX, this is not possible.