# How to create MySQL DB in PhpStorm?

Tags: mysql, phpstorm

I am trying to create a new MySQL DB in PhpStorm, but when I add table to `information_schema` I get this error:

> Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'

In addition, when I create a new DB and test connection I get this pop-up window:

> The specified user/password combination is rejected: "[42000][1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db'"

and I don't have password.

Comment: Wait, how come you'll add table to `information_schema`? It's the System schema of MySQL. Of course you won't have permission to do so.

Comment: So, how can I add a new table?

Comment: Try make all tables and databases with phpmyadmin or heidisql etc.. and then just connect the db with the project you want

Comment: MySQL basics: Create a new schema & add your custom tables there.

Comment: but I get this error:[42000][1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'new_schema'

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `information_schema` Database is the `MySQL` system schema. You shouldn't try to edit this `Database`

If you want to create a new `table` you should create that table in a new `database`. If your credentials are right you're able to create new `databases` running the following command in the console of your `MySQL` environment.

```
create database <database_name>
```

Comment: Thanks. Another question: how can I write a query that retrieve data from this database in javascript or jquery?

Comment: @yoni First you should try to create what you want for yourself. And if it then doesn't work or you're not able to figure it out. You should ask questions about it, To get you started take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser) example