# Quick and dirty connection to a database with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, database

I am trying to connect to a database using JavaScript. 
I have read that it is not recommended to use Client-side to connect to the database, for multiple reasons. But right now I am just trying to make a working local version.

What are some suggestions for getting a working local version? Am I able to get it done with purely JavaScript even tho it is bad practice? Or do I need assistance by php/ajax to make it work?

I have no experience with PHP.

Comment: Not only is it not recommended, but also it is impossible (that might be one of the "multiple reasons"). You physically can't connect to a database (necessarily hosted on a server) directly from a browser.

Comment: Use nodeJs to code javascript server side and set up a connection. Communicate between client and server using javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to SQL Server database from JavaScript in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i thought it's impossible until i just saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser).

but even if it is possible, **don't do it!** with this solution, every user can see the database connection parameters like username and pwd and therefore mess with your DB.

Instead, learn how to access a DB using PHP and use that in your local environment already. Its really not that complicated, you can find many instructions and tutorials if you're looking around

Comment: Thanks for actually showing that it is possible. While still advising against it.

Comment: why do i have the feeling that you are gonna try it out.. I can't stress this enough: **`don't do it`** :)  anyway, there is a good chance that it won't work anymore since the post of my link is over 8 years old

Comment: Actually it was my boss that wanted me to do "bad practice" without php because i don't have experience with php.
Now I am trying to make it work with php and xampp :)