# vsts extension making database calls

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops

I'm investigating building a VSTS Extension that can call an external SQL database passing a task ID, display the results in a task, and pass back an update if needed back to the SQL database. I have been looking for a while for a microsoft help doc that will answer this question but have not had any luck. Is it possible to interact with an external SQL database using a VSTS Extension? If so, is there any documentation out there that I missed?

Comment: UI extension? No. You'd need to host it on an external Azure website or self-hosted IIS instance and then can into it from the extension over a REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn’t the built-in api to do with database in VSTS extension, the VSTS extension uses [Data storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/data-storage?view=vsts) to store data.

Anyway, you just need to do it directly with some libraries, for example:

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;

var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";

connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

rs.Open("SELECT * FROM table", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
   document.write(rs.fields(1));
   rs.movenext;
}

rs.close;
connection.close;
```

Related thread: [How to connect to SQL Server database from JavaScript in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser)

The better way is that you can build a API project (e.g. web api) to do with database (need to be accessible from internet), then you can call that API with necessary data in you VSTS extension.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I needed.