# Using HTML/Js to access SQL database

Tags: javascript, html, sql, sqlite

Is there any way I could use HTML or JavaScript to make GET/POST requests directly on SQLite database. I want to add rows to the database and be able to retrieve data and display it on a webpage?

P.S. I know I could use PHP but I am not very comfortable with it.

Comment: your question is a bit vague, but a good technology for this is couch db. See https://couchdb.apache.org/

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser

Comment: @sakurashinken nice suggestion but hardly what I'd call an _"SQL database"_

Comment: Do you have any particular _"SQL database"_ in mind? MySQL / MariaDB? MS SQL Server? SQLite?

Comment: @Phil I want to use SQLite.

Comment: You can use NodeJS to code the back end part using javascript and use whichever SQL DB you want.

Comment: https://github.com/olsonpm/sqlite-to-rest

Comment: @Phil Thats why the suggestion is a comment, not an answer. Honestly, hitting a db with a post request with SQL in the body sounds like a horrible mess.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your application requirements are, It is not advisable to query SQL directly from the client. 
Although you can use library like:

> http://www.js-data.io/docs/js-data-sql

which has a SQL adapter so that you can query it directly using JS.