# Can I create a database change based on a dependency on a website with no access to the database?

Tags: javascript, sql, web

Currently we are able to write stored procedures to update fields, like a status field from active to inactive, based off of the selection of another field, like when a member type is changed from member to non-member.  This information can then be displayed on a website.

In the near future we will not have access to write stored procedures to the database anymore.  I am wondering if there's a way to change the display of fields, or even change the field in the database, using javascript or something similar?

I know this may not be a secure option, but I'm just wondering if the possibility is there or if anyone has done this.  I came across a question that seemed to point in that direction of opening up a connection to the database, but if we won't have credentials to access then I'm not sure this is an option.

[How to connect to SQL Server database from JavaScript in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser)

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: What basically every website in the world does is have code on the server that communicates with JavaScript in the browser and also with a database server, performing queries and updates as necessary.

Comment: The answer in the question you linked to uses ActiveX, which is insecure and also only works in Internet Explorer, and even then is usually blocked by company policies these days. As pointy said, use a server side language to create suitable queries (e.g. Update or Insert queries, or maybe just statements to execute existing stored procedures) to modify the database data.