# Check database connection from the browser using Emberjs (or javascript)

Tags: javascript, database, ember.js, browser

I'd like to check a (random) database connection directly from my **client-side** app without running it through a server.

The reason for this, is that I don't want the database credentials to ever go through my server.

Any idea if and how this is possible?

(I'm using Emberjs, so ideally I'd like to use Ember to do it)

Comment: Do I assume correctly that the user will enter the database credentials? Did you checked out [TypeORM](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm)? It supports Browser as plattform as well as many databases out there.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I guess [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser) gives me somewhat of an answer. I'm still curious if there's a more up to date answer.

Comment: Probably not. The server application always acts as a middle layer between the user and the database. Users generally aren't trusted to connect to the database directly and most database don't implement any kind of encryption by default making it difficult to connect to them securely. It's not impossible to do, but probably far enough off the beaten path that you'll be on your own for figuring out how.