# Is it possible to directly connect frontend to the database?

Tags: database, frontend, javascript-framework, web-frameworks, webdev.webserver

I came across this joke the other day. Someone on the internet was asking why do we need a backend, just connect the frontend to the database.

It seemed funny at first, but really is it possible to create a framework which handles frontend and backend at the same time?

Routing and listing views or grids all happen in the same function.

Technically I can't think of a reason why not!

Comment: This question has been asked before, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser

Answer (score 13):

Technically you can, but practically its useless for any serious applications, Some reasons from top of my head -

- At some point, you will expose all your credentials in browser.
- If you have any novel algorithm, which run's in backend, now you have to expose them to everyone.
- Your database is exposed, anyone can query the data from your db, just by running a db query in browser console, which exposes other users data too.
- Authentication & Authorisations are big joke, if you have no backend.
- Think of big applications like amazon, 100s of services, developed and deployed independently, in different languages, all at once in browser ? and only in javascript ? The client machine will die.

Many more.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes, it is pretty much possible. **However, it is not secure at all.**

Simply, you will keep database username and password in client side, which is quite silly.