Connect to mssql database in javascript webapp
I'm writing a webapp which is a recreation of a request system we had (server where it lived died unexpectedly) where they select a customer, I connect to the database and populate some fields on screen for them, they edit and submit, and I insert a new record into the database.
It will be hosted on a server only accessible on our intranet and only used by 4 people. Security is not a concern. I can force people to use Firefox, Edge, or Chrome to use it if there are compatibility issues.
I've found two suggested solutions and neither work. Firstly ActiveXObject which to my understanding is obsolete and no longer supported. (is it still supported on IE? I might be able to convince my boss to allow that) Second node.js, but tutorials all say you start the connection with
const sql = require('mssql')

which gives my browser console this message Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
Looking into that error I see that as individual browsers not supporting node.js so that's a nogo as well. So, what can I use for my task?
Edit: Adding
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
into my html changed the require not defined to a complaint saying the mssql module is not loaded. So I suspect if I find a different/additional script to load that should solve my issue. Just need to find it.

Node.js is one of possible solutions but node apps are executed at the server, not in your browser. You should definitely spend a couple of hours on the node.js Express framework tutorial, there are literally tons of these available for free. Come back with more questions after that.

I looked through some express tutorials and the examples on expressjs.com, but I don't see any DB connection examples.
I did introduce express into my project, downloading the needed dependencies. I have a package-lock.json, package.json, and server.js file. The server.js file calls app.use(express.static('public')) to bring up the html, css, and js in the public folder. But I'm still getting the same require not defined error, even though I successfully use const express=require('express') in the server.js
I tried moving some code from index to server and that just crashes.

The express.static is not the way to go. You need a server-side processing. Continue the tutorial up to the point where they show how to build pages that handle GET/POST requests.

You must setup a server with an application to handle API requests between the web client (browser) and a sql database server. The server application can use a variety of supported languages including javascript (server side node application), C#, Java, Python, Go, etc.
While security and scalable performance may not be a concern for your application, they are a common need. As such, current examples you find will use an API layer (a server side application) between a web browser and the SQL Server to manage access.

Does this mean I can't test directly with live server? I have to move everything to the app server and test from there? I should still be able to read console output yes?

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript-in-the-browser

Read console output? Not directly in a web browser without a web application or API setup in between. You need to connect using a native or ODBC driver (the client software that communicates with the DB) with database credentials. As far as I am aware that would be done from a server or desktop application. For development you can see console output also from Visual Studio or SQL Server Management Studio to view output.

I did see that 15 year old post and tried it, but it's utilizing activeobjectx which is no longer supported by any modern browsers.

That post does a better job listing the reasons it is no longer supported and lists some alternatives.

Does this mean I can't test directly with live server? I have to move everything to the app server and test from there?

BTW I brought what I had over to our app server that is running our other JS webapps and got the same error.
